# Using C++ base class constructors?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++11

While working with templates I ran into a need to make a base class constructors accessible from inherited classes for object creation to decrease copy/paste operations.
I was thinking to do this through `using` keyword in same manner with functions case, but that not work.

```
class A
{
public: 
    A(int val) {}
};

class B : public A
{
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    C(const string &val) {}
};

class D : public A
{
public:
    D(const string &val) {}
    using A::A;              // g++ error: A::A names constructor
};

void main()
{
    B b(10);                // Ok.   (A::A constructor is not overlapped)
    C c(10);                // error: no matching function to call to 'C::C(int)'
}
```

So my question: Is there any way to import a base class constructors after new ones in inherited class been declared?

Or there is only one alternative to declare new constructors and call a base ones from initializer list?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Fixed now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use base class's constructors and assignment operator in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226634/how-to-use-base-classs-constructors-and-assignment-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Prefer initialization:

```
class C : public A
{
public:
    C(const string &val) : A(anInt) {}
};
```

In C++11, you can use inheriting constructors (which has the syntax seen in your example `D`).

**Update:** Inheriting Constructors have been available in GCC since version 4.8.

---

If you don't find initialization appealing (e.g. due to the number of possibilities in your actual case), then you might favor this approach for some TMP constructs:

```
class A
{
public: 
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}
    void init(int) { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A() {}
    void init(int) { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    C() : A() {}
    void init(int) { std::cout << "C\n"; }
};

class D : public A
{
public:
    D() : A() {}
    using A::init;
    void init(const std::string& s) { std::cout << "D -> " << s << "\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    B b; b.init(10);
    C c; c.init(10);
    D d; d.init(10); d.init("a");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding comment, because SO keeps suggesting it, I prefer `using` syntax, because it's way shorter in usual cases and seems way cleaner to me.

Answer (score 124):

Yes, Since C++11:

```
struct B2 {
    B2(int = 13, int = 42);
};
struct D2 : B2 {
    using B2::B2;
// The set of inherited constructors is
// 1. B2(const B2&)
// 2. B2(B2&&)
// 3. B2(int = 13, int = 42)
// 4. B2(int = 13)
// 5. B2()

// D2 has the following constructors:
// 1. D2()
// 2. D2(const D2&)
// 3. D2(D2&&)
// 4. D2(int, int) <- inherited
// 5. D2(int) <- inherited
};
```

For additional information see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: This is not working for me. I get a "No instance of constructor matches the argument list".

Comment: @charlesrockbass This means that your B2 has no constructor matches your argument list or the constructor is not in accessible visibility

Comment: How would this syntax look if you have to specify namespace? 
For example with the following class: `struct my_container : std::vector<int>{}`

Comment: @Kartoffel, 1) `using base=std::vector<int>;` 2) `using base::base;`

Answer (score 14):

No, that's not how it is done. Normal way to initialize the base class is in the initialization list :

```
class A
{
public: 
    A(int val) {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B( int v) : A( v )
  {
  }
};


void main()
{
    B b(10);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to declare constructors in each of the derived classes, and then call the base class constructor from the initializer list:

```
class D : public A
{
public:
    D(const string &val) : A(0) {}
    D( int val ) : A( val ) {}
};

D variable1( "Hello" );
D variable2( 10 );
```

C++11 allows you to use the using A::A syntax you use in your decleration of D, but C++11 features aren't supported by all compilers just now, so best to stick with the older C++ methods until this feature is implemented in all the compilers your code will be used with.

Comment: Are you sure it compiles? How is A initialized in the 1st constructor?

Comment: Ah yeah, rushed the example a little.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A
{
public: 
    A(int val) {}
    A(string name) {}
};

class B : public A
{
using A::A;
};
```

Addition to other answers, in case there are several constuctors with the base class, and you just want to inherit some of them, you can delete the unwanted.

```
 class B : public A
 {
    using A::A;
    B(string) = delete;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good discussion about [superclass constructor calling rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules). You always want the base class constructor to be called *before* the derived class constructor in order to form an object properly. Which is why this form is used

```
  B( int v) : A( v )
  {
  }
```