# How to define strong ID types in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, types

How to define strong ID types in C++11? It's posible to done alias of integer types but getting warnings from compiler when you mix types?

E.g:

```
using monsterID = int;
using weaponID = int;

auto dragon = monsterID{1};
auto sword = weaponID{1};

dragon = sword; // I want a compiler warning here!!

if( dragon == sword ){ // also I want a compiler warning here!!
    // you should not mix weapons with monsters!!!
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with typedefs. Make new types. There's something in Boost IIRC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18251447/560648

Comment: Of interest is this proposed new feature for C++1y: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3515.pdf

Comment: @user1131467, so it's not posible to do it now, without using a own class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If youre using boost, try [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html)

Example from the documentation:

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, a)
void f(int x);  // (1) function to handle simple integers
void f(a x);    // (2) special function to handle integers of type a 
int main(){
    int x = 1;
    a y;
    y = x;      // other operations permitted as a is converted as necessary
    f(x);       // chooses (1)
    f(y);       // chooses (2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a great solution. But I was looking if with new standard C++11 it's posible to do it without using macros, or fully classes.