# "class VARIABLE" in declaration of variable for template class?

Tags: c++, templates

Recently, I saw a unfamiliar statement for C++ template, something like:

```
    x3::rule<class expression> const expression("expression");
    x3::rule<class term> const term("term");
    x3::rule<class factor> const factor("factor");
```

It's an exmaple source code for Boost.Spirit.X3(https://github.com/djowel/spirit_x3/blob/master/example/x3/calc1.cpp#L41)

It seems that these lines declare expression, term, and factor variable of template class x3::rule. What's curious thing is <class expression> part for example. I've never seen such statemet ever.

When declare a variable of template class, one specify 'a type' as template argument, so I can guess 'class expression' means some type. However, expression is a name of variable and the combination of a keyword 'class', that is, 'class expression' seems awkward. Further more, the variable 'expression' is not yet declared when instantiate x3::rule. Is it something like forward declaration using variable name?

Please let me know how these declarations work and the term for such statements if any.

Comment: It's just using a "temporary type" as the argument. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232293/how-to-define-different-types-for-the-same-class-in-c (and holy cow, how did I find that?)

Comment: @chris It wasn't a difficult or complicated thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the statement :

```
x3::rule<class expression> const expression("expression");
```

`class expression` *declares* a new type (`expression`) AND use it as a template argument of the `rule<>` template. It is often called a temporary type, since it will be used nowhere else (the type is incomplete).

- In your example, `expression`, `term` and `factor` all have different types.
- In C++, a variable can have the same name as a type, which is what the author does here.

---

Here is a minimal [demonstration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29546de38ad502dc) :

```
template<class T>
class rule
{
    public:
       std::string rules;  
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  rule<class myexpression> myexpression;
  rule<class myexpression2> myexpression2;

  myexpression.rules = "hello";
  myexpression2.rules = "hello2";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it serve a purpose to name the temporary type and the variable the same ? Because if not, it is just confusing the reader, why not write `x3::rule<class expression_tag> const expression("expression")` instead ?

Comment: So, it's just another form of 'forward declaration' and it won't be a problem as far as noone access any member of that argument class. Thank you!