# how to use the operator of parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use base class's constructors and assignment operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226634/how-to-use-base-classs-constructors-and-assignment-operator-in-c)

```
class A
{
protected:
    void f();
}

class B : public A
{
protected:
    void f()
    {
         A::f();
    }
}
```

We can use the function of parent class in this way, but I don't know how to use the operator of parent class.

Comment: (I guessed this was C++; please correct if I guessed wrong by editing your question and putting the appropriate language tag.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226634/how-to-use-base-classs-constructors-and-assignment-operator-in-c has some examples of calling operators from a parent class in C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operators of user defined types are just member functions with funky names. So, it goes pretty similarly to your example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    A& operator++() { std::cout << "++A\n"; return *this; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B& operator++()
    {
        A::operator++();
        return *this;
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    ++b;
}
```