# derived assignment operator calling the one from a base

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

[In the best rated answer to the question from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226634/how-to-use-base-classs-constructors-and-assignment-operator-in-c/1226792#1226792), I don't understand how the derived assignment operator calls the assignment operator from the base class, i.e., this in this part of the code:

```
Derived& operator=(const Derived& d)
{
    Base::operator=(d);
    additional_ = d.additional_;
    return *this;
}
```

what does

```
Base::operator=(d)
```

mean? What does it do? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a call to a member function on the current object.  The current object inherited a function whose fully-qualified name is `Base::operator=`, and you can call it just like any other non-static member function.

Comment: Ben: Oh, so I need to think that "Base::operator=(d)" is called ON the derived object (as any other member function would be)! I thought along the lines that "entire functions" act on objects, I hadn't thought about smth in an actual body of the function doing that. True, true. So, this takes care for the base part of the assignment operation, and then I need of course to assign any extra data data Derived has. Got it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

`Base::operator=` calls the `Base` class version of `operator=` to copy the parts of the object that are part of `Base` and then the derived class copies the rest. Since the base class already does all the work required correctly why repeat the work, just reuse. So let's take this simplified example:

```
class Base
{
   std::string
      s1 ;
   int
      i1 ;
   public:
     Base& operator =( const Base& b)  // method #1
     {
        // trvial probably not good practice example
        s1 = b.s1 ;
        i1 = b.i1 ;

        return *this ;
     }
} ;

class Derived : Base
{
   double
     d1 ;
   public:
     Derived& operator =(const Derived& d ) // method #2
     {
       // trvial probably not good practice example
       Base::operator=(d) ;
       d1 = d.d1 ;
       return *this ;

     }

} ;
```

`Derived` will have three member variables, two from `Base`: `s1` and `i1` and one of it's own `d1`. So `Base::operator=` calls what I have labeled as `method #1` which copies the two variables that `Derived` inherited from `Base` which are `s1` and `i1` and so that all that is left to copy is `d1` which is what `method #2` takes care of.