# How correctly to write a copy constructor, destructor, and assignment operator when inheriting?

Tags: c++

This is correct?

```
class SearchString : public NString {

  DataForSearchInString dataForSearchInString;

public:
    SearchString():NString(){}
    SearchString(const char * data):NString(data){}
    SearchString(const SearchString & other) : NString(other), dataForSearchInString() {}

    SearchString& operator=(const SearchString& other)
    {
        NString::operator=(other);
        dataForSearchInString.setBegin(other.getBegin());
        return *this;
    }

    // if will be classes - children or there any virtual function then need to write "virtual ~SearchString() {}"  here 

    //  Some functions 
    inline const int getBegin() const {return dataForSearchInString.getBegin();} 
};
```

Comment: looks good, `SearchString():NString(){}` is unnecessary

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226634/how-to-use-base-classs-constructors-and-assignment-operator-in-c

Answer (score 0):

It seems OK, but I think you forget `DataForSearchInString(other.dataForSearchInString)`

```
class SearchString : public NString {

    DataForSearchInString dataForSearchInString;

public:
    SearchString():NString(){}
    SearchString(const char * data):NString(data){}
    SearchString(const SearchString & other) : 
                            NString(other),
                            DataForSearchInString(other.dataForSearchInString) {}
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    SearchString& operator=(const SearchString& other)
    {
        NString::operator=(other);
        dataForSearchInString.setBegin(other.getBegin());
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot, wrote the message correctly, but here exist some bugs.