# C++ Calling overloaded operator from within a class

Tags: c++

I have a class which inherits from another class, and I wish to call `[index]` to access the index'th element of some allocated storage.

Here is a minimal example:

```
class A
{
    protected:
    double *mem;

    double operator[](const size_t index)
    {
        return mem[index];
    }
}

class B : public A
{
    void function()
    {
        double var = this->operator[](0);
    }
}
```

So here I step around the problem by calling `this->operator[](0)` which is kind of messy.

Is this the correct way to access elements of `mem` considering that I don't have access to that variable from the derived class, or is there an alternative way?

Edit: I think it might be significant that I'm conforming to C++11, so can't call `mem[0]`?

*Edit, template classes*

As discussed below, the compiler error I see isn't showing up for this example, because there are no templates here.

To reproduce the compiler error:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    protected:
    double *mem;

    double operator[](const size_t index)
    {
        return mem[index];
    }
}

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
    void function()
    {
        double var = this->operator[](0);
    }
}
```

*Possible Solutions*

```
return this->operator[](0);
return (*this)[0];
return (this->mem)[0];
return *((this->mem)+0);
return (*this).mem[0];
return *((*this).mem+0);
```

... I think all of these do what I expect them to. Any more suggestions?

Even better solution:

```
return A::mem[0];
```

Comment: You can also do `(*this)[0];` or `mem[0]` directly.

Comment: "Is this the correct way to access elements of mem considering that I don't have access to that variable from the derived class" -- You do have access from the derived class because `mem` is declared `protected`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use base class's constructors and assignment operator in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226634/how-to-use-base-classs-constructors-and-assignment-operator-in-c)

Comment: "I'm conforming to C++11, so can't call mem[0]" a non sequitur.

Comment: @n.m. If the previous (2) edits are wrong please edit and change again

Comment: This is an open-ended question that is calling for a vague and possibly infinite set of suggestions, none of which are necessarily better than others. Please limit the scope of the question such that it can be answered with a single authoritative answer. For example, "Why doesn't `mem[0]` work?".

Comment: @n.m. Not true. Some of the suggestions are objectively better than the others. It isn't at all what `*((*this).mem + 0)` does, for example.

Comment: It is still impossible to provide a single authoritative answer to this question even if some of the suggestions are better (by what metric?) than some others.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). "Your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers".

Comment: @n.m. And yet, the suggestions, which are not "answers" are wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You could say `(*this)[0]`.

There's nothing stopping you from using `mem[0]` either though, in any version of C++.

Comment: Nothing except sanity. You shouldn't directly access base members when they're already "controlled" through a tidy interface. I'd actually make `mem` `private` as soon as possible.

Comment: I think anything declared as `protected` is fair game. If you're not supposed to access it, it should be `private`. But otherwise I agree, I was just pointing it out there is no mystery rule in C++11 that would prevent you from doing that if you really wanted to.

Comment: `mem` is protected, but I cannot access it! `error: 'mem' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: I just ran your code and I could access it just fine. I bet you didn't paste your exact code.

Comment: Additional info, I am using a template class?

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: If you want precise help you are going to have to post precise code and not just something that's kinda-sorta like what you actually have.

Comment: Granted, it was a good MCVE for the question you were actually asking.

Comment: @user3728501: Might want to make it a new question even. Maybe.

Comment: @user3728501: Solution and link to explanation is now in my answer.

Comment: @user3728501: Are you still there? "One sec" was four hours ago :(

Comment: "If you're not supposed to access it, it should be private". You are not supposed to access it and it should be private. If it isn't, send a PR.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is mostly a matter of preference, and other answers have given some options that use `(*this)[0]`, I tend to prefer a cleaner syntax that doesn't require use of `this` at all:

```cpp
return operator[](0);
```

Comment: Actually, I prefer this (answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good approach. You can make the call more pleasing by writing it as `(*this)[0]`.

However, if you don't mind bypassing the base class's interface (I wouldn't — I'd actually make `mem` `private`), you *can* write `mem[0]`!

If you're having trouble with that, it's due to something not in your testcase. For example, [if it's a base member in a class template, you may need to write `this->mem[0]` due to a C++ oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4643074/560648).

Comment: Why is `this->[0];` not allowed? Seems syntactically inconsistent?

Comment: @user3728501: It's not inconsistent.

Comment: I could call `this->Get(0)`, or `this->anyotherfunction()` ?

Comment: @user3728501: `[]` is not function call notation. You don't write `obj.[0]` so a lack of `ptr->[0]` is not an inconsistency.

Comment: ie; Why does the compiler not interpret `this->[N];` as `this->operator[](N);`